# How to enable javascript enabled countdown timer in php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, timer, clock

I have written php code for an examination portal using javascript enabled countdown timer. When i run my code in localhost its fine. But in server, the clock gets stopped after some time, what might be the problem? Below is the part of related codes. Thank you!!!
In portal.php

```
    <?php
    $_SESSION['exam_length'] = $all_questions[0]->exam_length;
    $_SESSION['start_time'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $end_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('+'.$_SESSION['exam_length'].'minutes',strtotime($_SESSION['start_time'])));
    $_SESSION['end_time'] = $end_time;
    ?>
    <div  class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-3" id="response" style="font-size: 25px;  position: fixed; right: -7px;"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function()
    {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET","response.php",false);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
        document.getElementById('response').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    },1000);


    exam_length =  '<?php echo (($all_questions[0]->exam_length)*60000); ?>';
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(function() { submitform(); },exam_length);

   </script>
```

In response.php:

```
<?php 
     session_start();
    if(($_SESSION['is_logged_in'])=="")
    {
        @header("location:../");
        exit;
    }
    $from_time1 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $to_time1 = $_SESSION['end_time'];
    $timefirst = strtotime($from_time1);
    $timesecond = strtotime($to_time1);
    $difference_second = $timesecond - $timefirst;
    echo gmdate("H:i:s",$difference_second);
    ?>
```

Comment: So what is the error? Look at what the server is returning. My guess is you are getting stopped for making too many HTTP Requests.

Comment: I think so, I am going to change the server to inpect it